# How to configure SNS notification for SES to receive in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

The project involves sending bulk emails using AWS SES. However, the response received after sending each email does not include the delivery status. In order to create a log that includes the delivery status, Do I need to use SNS? (Simple Notification Service). How to configure it in Typescript to retrieve the delivery notification in code so that I can write it with some other information to a CSV file later?